# Using a class as a type parameter which may or may not contain another type parameter

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I am working with Generics and i encountered a problem.
So i have a `Node class` which has a `type parameter<T>` which extends comparable.

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Node<T>> {

    private T info;
    private Node next;
    private Node previous;

}
```

Now, i have designed another class say a `Priority Queue class` which also contains a comparable type parameter.

```
public class PriorityQueue<Item extends Comparable<Item>> 
implements Iterable<Item> {

....

}
```

But when i try and use a Node class as a Type in my Priority Queue class like this:

```
private MaxPriorityQueue<Node> maxPriorityQueue;
```

It gives me an error saying , *`Type parameter Node is not defined within bounds, should implement java.lang.comparable`*.

I think i am conceptually wrong at implementing this. 
What should be the correct way?

Is there a way i can change Priority Queue class, so that it can take any class(say `A`) which implements comparable interface (irrespective of the fact whether `A` contains type parameter or not) as a type parameter.?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi : Sorry i edited the question.

Comment: full example here: https://ideone.com/6e0QZ4

Comment: Why are you using ```Node``` as a raw type? Adding a type argument fixes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your requirements, you need to enforce your PriorityQueue to accept objects that implement the comparable interface for themselves. In that case, you just need:

```
class PriorityQueue<Item extends Comparable<Item>> {
```

and eventually if you want a type parameter for the payload of your Node:

```
class Node<T> implements Comparable<Node<T>> {
```

so that you can do this:

```
private PriorityQueue<Node<Integer>> maxPriorityQueue;
```

Like here: https://ideone.com/GBnHp7 (?) (look at the comments as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what you have done. You just need to specify the type for `Node<T>` when you declare your queue, something like this:

```
private PriorityQueue<Node<String>> queue;
```

Good luck!